# KVM XML config file

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a KVM server that I expanded the LV of then rebooted. However now when booting I get the error:

error: Failed to create domain from /home/kvm/kvmx/kvmx.xml
error: (domain_definition):1: Document is empty
(null)
^

It appears the config file still exits however it is now empty. I attempted to replace the contents of the file with the correct previous information however it continues to wipe it on attempt to boot and fails again with the same error.

How would I got about solving this so the file doesn't get wiped on every reboot?

OS: Centos 6 64bit

I would appreciate any help you may have.

Answer (score 3):

How did you create the domxml file? The correct way is to use `virsh define` or `virsh edit` and not a direct edit of the file

Just noticed - your XML file was in the wrong location too. When you use `virsh` it will place the files where they belong

Answer (score 0):

Issue found.

I mistakenly looked over the fact that my disk ran out of space.